# Setting color of mapped image for ThreeJS particles

Tags: three.js

Originally I was using `ParticleSystem`, but I discovered that `Raycaster` does not work with it.  So I'm now modifying my code to simply use individual `Particle` objects.

The problem is, I can't seem to set the color of the image I'm mapping to the particles like I was able to with `ParticleSystem`.

I tried the following:

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("ball.png");

material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({

    size : 10,
    color: 0x00C1BF,
    map : texture,
    transparent : true,

});

// Generate some random points...
for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {

    var particle = new THREE.Particle(material);

    particle.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = particle.scale.z = 3;

    plot.add(particle);

}
```

But the color of `ball.png` remains the same.  If I comment out the image I'm mapping to the points, the colors are changing.  But it's not working with the mapped image.  When I was using `ParticleSystem`, inside the `for` loop where I generate the points, I was adding this:

```
colors[i] = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
colors[i].setHSL((x + 1000 ) / 2000, 1, 0.5);
```

And then set `particleSys.colors = colors;` outside the loop.  That changed the color of the points, but this doesn't seem to work with `Particle`.

I hate to keep bugging the community with questions like this, but I really would appreciate any guidance on this.  Many thanks, as always!  :)

Also, here's a link to `ball.png` that I'm using: http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples/textures/sprites/ball.png

Comment: What renderer are you using? Are you using three.js r.63? `ParticleBasicMaterial` has been deprecated; it is now `ParticleSystemMaterial`.

Comment: I'm using CanvasRenderer now.  Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Search the three.js `CanvasRenderer` examples.